# How to convert a string to array in php?

Tags: php

This is not the `explode` can solve

I have several array

```
$order
data: {5,3,2}

$title,
data: {USA, England, China}

$attribute
Same idea 

$type
Same idea
```

The $order has already exist some value
{5,3,2}  and 
for each  has its $title,$attribute,$type value correspondingly

```
eg. 5 USA  att5 type5
```

I would like to sort the order to {2,3,5} and the corresponding data in other array will be sorted too.

```
eg. {2,3,5}
```

For the array $title afterwards

is

```
{China, England,USA}
```

How to implement this for all arrays? Thank you

My idea is using an associative array , and i can sort the key, and everything is done. However, I can not generate the array

My idea array:

```
$records = array(5 => array("title" => "USA",   "att" => "add5"),
                 3 => array("title" => "England",  "att" => "add3"),
                 2 => array("title" => "China", "att" => "add2"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$order = array(5, 3, 2);    // or $order = array("5", "3", "2");
$title = array("USA", "England", "China");
$att = array("Att 1", "Att 2", "Att 3");
$type = array("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3");

$records = array();
foreach ($order as $i => $o) 
    $records[$o] = array("title" => $title[$i], "att" => $att[$i], "type" => $type[$i]);

ksort($records, SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($records);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After these lines on your script

```
$string = substr($string, 0, -1);
$records="array (".$string.");";
```

You can add

```
eval("\$records = $records;");
```

You can read about the eval function at http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php and why you should be really careful when using it

Comment: first of all, it looks like this will not work with the input OP shown. secondly, when in doubt - do **not** use `eval`

Comment: "looks like" => enough to vote down?  And if eval is a practical solution, why not point it out?  Especially if a warning accompanies it's use...as it does.

Comment: @Stefan: if you look at the input (above), you might see what i mean by "looks like"

Comment: @Stefan and regarding `eval` being practical, please, reconsider... can you be sure what outcome will it do when input (even slightly) changes?

Comment: @poncha: "looks like" means "looks like" in my dictionary - it doesn't mean "confirmed wrong".  And with "practical" I mean "working in a specific case", and if it works in this case, why not point it out? That said, I wouldn't do it myself and furthermore it "looks like" the quotes and double quotes in the string will raise a parse error (unconfirmed though).

Comment: @Stefan: unless there is a unique and undeniable reason for using [`eval`](http://php.net/eval), it's use is highly discouraged, even by Zend (read the manual). This is a very dangerous tool, and using it for such a reason is not really adequate, regardless whether or not it delivers result with this specific input. that was the major point for my -1

Comment: @poncha: Dangerous or not, if it is a solution, it's a solution.  And (as I said) the danger of using eval was specifically and clearly pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

where one `explode` is not enough, two `explode`s can help ;)

```
$records = Array();
foreach(explode("\n", trim($string)) as $line)
{
   list($order,$title,$attribute,$type) = explode(",", $line);
   $records[$order] = Array("title" => $title, "attribute" => $attribute, "type" => $type);
}
ksort($records);
```

Comment: that's assuming the **input** is the string like you shown - a lot of lines in format `$order,$title,$attribute,$type`. if not, then consider a different approach.

Comment: now that your intentions are clear, please, look at @Tarik's answer about `multisort`.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems i need not using this if i have created an array

Answer (score 1):

instead of converting from a string to array you can build it

```
$result = array();
$countItem=0;
foreach ($order as $itemID)
{
     $result [$countItem] = array('id' => $itemID, 'title' => $title[$countItem],   'attribute' => $att[$countItem],'type'=>$type[$countItem]);
     $countItem++;
}
```

and then sort it by id

Comment: one comment: single quotes will not work here. you will get a lot of lines with literal values like `$title[$countItem]`...

Comment: You will have an array $order which you can return

Comment: what did it return? and did you initialize the $countItem

Comment: sure , and i tried type in the countItem manually, it return 
Array ( [0] => Array ( 'title' =>'title1', 'attribute' => 'att1' 'type' => 'txt' ) )  but it different from what i need.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. You can notice Array ( [0] => Array ( 'title' , Array ( [1] => Array ( 'title' in your code, however, in my case $order[0] and $order[1] are not necessarily 0 and 1. It is just the first and second item in order.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you clear up what is the purpose of this code so we can understand and help better

Comment: +1 to that. please, provide clear input and output samples so we can understand what you really want

Comment: try to use $itemID as index for the new array input - i edited the answer -

Answer (score 1):

things are now more clear
for this i recommend using `array_multisort`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: My idea was using assositive array, wouldn't it easier to implement, all i need is ksort, but the problem is I still can not generate the array .

Comment: :) yes, and You will get the same output from the code in the link